# inner div floating outisde parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working on [this website](http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/tvshow.html).

For some reason on the last block on the right, my button floats outside the div (though it doesn't have a height). Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector `#see-more-button-container-lists` has a negative `margin-bottom`. Try with `margin-bottom:15px`. The same goes for `#see-more-button-container-lists:hover`.

Comment: thanks a lot, don't know how I missed that, I need a break !

Answer (score 0):

Change the css for `see-more-button-container-lists` from `margin-bottom: -15px` to `margin-bottom: 15px`.